# replacing a variable substring in a string in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all oldString's in string that are surrounded by whitespace, '.' , '(' or ')' using regex.

```
var string = ' (y) .y   y  rye';
var oldsString = 'y';
var regex = new RegExp('([.()\s])('+oldString+')([.()\s])','g');
var newString = 'x';
string = string.replace(regex, '$1'+newString+'$3');
```

setting regex to

```
var regex = new RegExp('([\.\(\)\s])('+oldString+')([\.\(\)\s])','g');
```

according to this website both methods should work:
http://regex101.com/r/mM4xJ2
but when i try the code in node it only sets string to

```
' (x) .y   y  rye'
```

not

```
' (x) .x   x  rye'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double escape since you're compiling concatenated strings with a variable to a RegExp object:

```
var string = ' (y) .y   y  rye';
var oldString = 'y';
var regex = new RegExp('([.()\\s])('+oldString+')([.()\\s])','g');
var newString = 'x';
string = string.replace(regex, '$1'+newString+'$3');
```

This returns correctly:

```
' (x) .x   x  rye'
```

Comment: It fails if 2 y is separated by 1 `[.()\\s]`, eg. ` y.y `

Comment: If the string is ` y.y ` you cannot have a character match twice with RegEx since the first match ` y.` consumes the `.` prefix from the latter substring portion `.y `, so the correct result *should* be `" x.y "` as opposed to `" x.x "` despite all common sense.

Comment: ... and since js regex does not support lookbehind you can't do it with it this simply. I'm just pointing out so the questioner would know.